# VBA: type mismatch error on finding elements from another list

Tags: excel, vba

i am working on the exercise below but i need some help. It is giving runtime error 13. I am a beginner, can you please help me solve it? Of course other ways of solving the problem are more than welcomed. There are 2 lists (1: Sheet2.Range("E5:E1324") and 2:SearchRange = Sheet1.Range("F2:F4178"))
, of long text format and not exact match, list 1 contains a phrase of the information in list2. I need to know how many times data in list 2 is mentioned in list 1 (as i know there are times it goes up to 7)
Thank you a lot,
Ana

```
Sub countvalues()
' count how many times data in Description Range is listed in SearchRange

Dim i As Integer 'for looping in Description
Dim j As Integer   'for looping in SearchRange
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim FoundData As Range
Dim Description As Range
Dim SearchRange As Range

Set Description = Sheet2.Range("E5:E1324")
Set SearchRange = Sheet1.Range("F2:F4178")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Counter = 0

For i = 5 To 1324   'trying with a narrower range for testing purpose

        For j = 2 To 4178
            Set FoundData = SearchRange.Find(Sheet2.Range("E" & i))
            'On Error Resume Next
            Counter = FoundData.Count + 1

        Next j

    Sheet2.Range("F" & i) = Counter

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use COUNTIF formula?

Comment: Hello, dear @Stefani. You could get faster and better answers if you could also include some example data set for the people to work on, what you have tried so far, what went well and what didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try the adapted code, please. It will work only if your string used for search (`What`) is contained in the searched range cells... I mean "test searched" will be found in "test searched today". But "test searched today" will not be found in "test searched"

```
Sub testFindSimilar()
 Dim d As Long, strFirstAddress As String
 Dim Counter As Long, lastR1 As Long, lastR2 As Long
 Dim shD As Worksheet, shS As Worksheet, cel As Range

  Set shD = sheet1
  Set shS = sheet2
  lastR1 = shS.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  lastR2 = shD.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 For d = 5 To lastR2
    Set cel = shS.Range("F2:F" & lastR1).Find(What:=shD.Range("E" & d).value, _
                      After:=shS.Range("F2"), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not cel Is Nothing Then
        strFirstAddress = cel.Address
        Do
            Set cel = shS.Range("F2:F" & lastR1).FindNext(cel)
            If Not cel Is Nothing Then
                Counter = Counter + 1
            End If
        Loop Until cel.Address = strFirstAddress
    End If
    shD.Range("F" & d).value = Counter
    Counter = 0: strFirstAddress = ""
 Next d
End Sub
```

If you wont to test less rows, you can replace last rows variable with your testing numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried it, this time it is giving run-time error '1004'. Unable to get the CountIf property of the WorksheetFunction class. This is my first exercise, so maybe my questions are very basic. Thank you again.

Comment: @Stefani: Strange... Is it possible that your string/value in `sheet2.Range("E" & i).value` to be longer then 255 characters? If I remember well, `CountIf` has such a limitation...

Comment: yes, some go up to 800 in Sheet1. They are long descriptions. Descriptions in sheet2 are kind of 'subset' of the ones in sheet1. If i had to do it manually in excel Ctrl+F does it, but it takes a lot of time. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Stefani: I am trying another solution. Unfortunately, using arrays solution suffers from the same string limitation. I will check if I well remember this aspect, too...

Comment: thank you so much, was the way i was trying to solve it wrong? 
Is there any channel you recommend for learning? I am new to VBA and i am checking the tutorials in the link below: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHO5NIcZAc4&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5
Note: not sure if referring youtube videos is permitted here, if not please inform me so i delete it. Thank you a lot

Comment: @Stefani: Please, test the updated code. Forget now about the better learning way.. I tried commenting the code lines. Confirm, please that you understand the meaning...

Comment: i tried it, this time it gives no error but it is not working. For under 255 case, there are sometimes errors, whereas for greater than 255 it is not working at all.

Comment: @Stefani: What does "not working" mean? Didn't it return the `CountIf` result where you need?  Didn't it find any occurrences? What errors do "sometimes" appear and in what circumstances? Wen stopped on error, what value is shown when moving the cursor over `sheet1.Range("F" & s).value`? What value has `s` in such a case? Please, also explain what "for greater than 255 it is not working at all" means. Doesn't the iteration work? Doesn't it return any `Counter`? Can you paste here two such strings to be matched/counted and they are not?

Comment: for the first part of the code, many times it is giving the wrong output, for greater than 255 character cases the output is 0.
for example: "The Engineer notes that, the Contractor has failed to incorporate and install the ROP Stakeholder minimum outlet requirements in ROP areas for the following Rooms."  output is 0 , but it has to be 4.

Comment: **Can you post, please, the two other cases which could not be found by `CountIf`**? If those notes are manually input, it looks impossible to be the same. They maybe be trimmed before, or I do not know in which way to preliminary be processed... VBA can help a lot, but it cannot make comparisons as a human being if strings to ne compared are different...

Comment: I am not sure i understood you properly. After executing the code i cross checked with ctrl+f. This is how i know about the outputs are not correct. "The Engineer notes that, the Contractor has failed to incorporate and install the ROP Stakeholder minimum outlet requirements in ROP areas for the following Rooms." This text is part of the information in Sheet 1 in 4 cells, and in each of them is followed by different room numbers. Thank you

Comment: @Stefani: If your strings contains different characters ("different room numbers"), such a code will never return what you need. Sorry...

Comment: think that a code including the method "find" could do it ?

Comment: @Stefani: Sorry, I had to leave. Theoretically, yes... But only if you search part of a string in a bigger one which contains that part. I mean, it can find "The Engineer notes that, the Contractor has failed to incorporate and install the ROP Stakeholder minimum outlet requirements in ROP areas for the following Rooms." in "The Engineer notes that, the Contractor has failed to incorporate and install the ROP Stakeholder minimum outlet requirements in ROP areas for the following Rooms. xxx"... Is that your case? If yes, I can help with a piece of code. Without knowing your data, I cannot do it

Comment: @Stefani: if you know that some specific characters number from the string will difer, `What:=shD.Range("E" & d).value` can be adapted by truncating it removing that number of characters. Using `Left (string, Len(string) - NoChar)`. Where `NoChar` is the nomber of characters in discussion...